# Magento 2.2.4 - Free Shipping Cart Price Rule ONLY for given products

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.4, free-shipping

We are trying to include a free shipping method for Specific SKU/Products that have a subtotal over 500 when in the cart by themselves.

This is accomplished by using the conditions:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
        SKU  is one of  XX-1103, XX-1201, XX-1301, XX-...  

Subtotal  equals or greater than  500
```

And the actions:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    SKU  is one of  XX-1103, XX-1201, XX-1301, XX-...  

Free Shipping: For Matching Items Only
```

This all works when adding the specified SKUs and subtotal over 500, however the issue is that the customer can add any other products to help get over 500, or even be over 500 with correct SKUs, but still add other products to the order and the Free Shipping will still be available even though non-qualifying SKUs are currently in the cart.

We have tried plenty of mix and match methods within the conditions and actions, but can't find anything to satisfy this issue.

Any ideas??